# Dual boot GRUB error

Tags: grub, ubuntu-10.10, multi-boot

I recently vacuumed my computer, and when I turned it on afterwards I got a grub error saying no such device.

I have a 80 Gb SSD running Win 7 and a 500 Gb spinny where Ubuntu wa installed.

When I opened the box, it turned out the S-ATA connection on the 500 Gb had come off. I attached it, but still nothing.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Never*** vacuum a computer!  Static electricity kills!

It's entirely possible that you fried a drive or something else - do all the devices show up properly in the BIOS?  If they don't, well, you have a drive failure to investigate (presumably the drive with your bootloader on it is intact, but you don't give specifics as to which that is and where you're trying to boot).  If they do seem to work, I'd recommend booting to a LiveCD (or slaving the drives to another machine) to check them out.

Comment: All disks are shown in BIOS and when I run the Live cd, all partitions are displayed. I tried formating the old Ubuntu partition and install again. The installation halts at the end with a 'fata grub error'

Comment: Hmm, maybe just some damage to the data itself (but that's pretty unlikely, to the extent that I've never actually heard of it happening).  Still, it's the only thing that fits the symptoms - you should probably rebuild grub from the ground up. (I don't know the specifics of that process, unfortunately - I'm sure somebody else will chime in.)

Comment: I had some other trouble after upgrading from 10.10 to 11.04. I tried the 10.10 Live CD, and suddenly everything worked out fine. Thanks for the answers, though. It helped to know it was a software problem.

Comment: @erikric - Glad to see it wasn't anything serious.  But for future reference, I wasn't exaggerating - NEVER vacuum a PC!

Comment: Hmmm, I have done it all my life, and never had trouble with it. Of course I ground myself first, and only vacuum the fans and heat sinks.

Comment: @erikric - Then you've been lucky, especially if you're vacuuming the fans and letting them spin freely...they can act like mini-generators if that's the case and could potentially damage components that way as well.